# Bootstrap - Full width layout two columns with different colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem with this is that I can't get it right with background coloring. Left column always 'bleeds' into the top of the right column.
Help guys, I'm trying to fix this for three days now.

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row blue-background">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1">
            <h1>Text here</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-12 gray-background">
            <h2>Another text here</h2>
        </div>
    </div><!--  .row -->
</div><!--  .container-fluid -->
```

And in my custom CSS file this classes have only background: /value_of_color/

My CSS code:

```
.blue-background {
    background-color: blue;
}

.gray-background {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

Comment: please show your css.... i tried it and it seems to work

Comment: @FalcoB Here's what happens when I do that..  [link](http://www.bootply.com/kriG1aUc0f)

Comment: okay, then its the provided answer! your color class is in the row, not in the col

Comment: When I do that, it looks exactly like this.. [link](http://www.bootply.com/y9Yrpp4lKg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this-

```css
.blue-background {
    background-color: blue;
}
.blue-background:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

.gray-background {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="blue-background">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1">
              <h1>Text here</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-12 gray-background">
              <h2>Another text here</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--  .row -->
</div><!--  .container-fluid -->
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 blue-background">
            <h1>Text here</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-12 gray-background">
            <h2>Another text here</h2>
        </div>
    </div><!--  .row -->
</div><!--  .container-fluid -->
```