# Get Two Columns with different background colours that extend to screen edge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32738376/1814446).**

I trying to create two columns on a webpage have different background colours that extend to the screen edges.  But the content of the columns needs to stay within the bootstrap boxed width.

It should look like this:
[image]

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32738376/1814446) which almost worked but the inner content wasn't correctly aligned within the boxed width, especially on large screens over 1600px.  It basically ended up looking like:

[image]

Below, is a code snippet of the closest I could get to it working, it may be the wrong approach entirely:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="background: bisque;">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <h1>Normal Boxed Width</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" style="background-color: aquamarine; padding: 0">
  <div>
   <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h1>Left Panel</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae doloribus unde, distinctio a autem, soluta nulla similique. Vero natus deleniti, culpa consequuntur eveniet beatae laudantium in fuga mollitia sapiente! Assumenda!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 gray-background" style="background-color: rebeccapurple;padding: 10px;color:#fff">
              <h1>Right Panel</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, beatae amet est repellendus optio, exercitationem distinctio quasi ut, sapiente, nihil sed libero facere fugiat eaque numquam nulla mollitia suscipit nobis.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!--  .row -->
</div><!--  .container-fluid -->
```

Comment: You could use the 48-grid in Bootstrap-sass for more flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 beta**

The concept is still the same in Bootstrap 5. Use a absolute position pseudo element on the column(s) to create the appearance of a `container` inside a `container-fluid`...

[Bootstrap 5 example](https://codeply.com/p/cPrqOfhXCG)

***Or,*** use `container-fluid` and nest smaller grid columns inside the outer columns with background color...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 bg-info">
            <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <div class="col-9"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-danger">
            <div class="row justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-9"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap 5 nesting example](https://www.codeply.com/p/7DSjHPMAXb)

---

**Bootstrap 4**

The concept is still the same in Bootstrap 4, but the -xs- infix no longer exists.

[Bootstrap 4 example](https://codeply.com/go/zGEaXLFu9K)

---

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

Use another wrapper DIV around a 2nd container...

```
<div class="container" style="background: bisque;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>Normal Boxed Width</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: aquamarine; padding: 0">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <h1>Left Panel</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae doloribus unde, distinctio a autem, soluta nulla similique. Vero natus deleniti, culpa consequuntur eveniet beatae laudantium in fuga mollitia sapiente! Assumenda!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 gray-background" style="background-color: rebeccapurple;padding: 10px;color:#fff">
                    <h1>Right Panel</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, beatae amet est repellendus optio, exercitationem distinctio quasi ut, sapiente, nihil sed libero facere fugiat eaque numquam nulla mollitia suscipit nobis.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--  .row -->
    </div>
    <!--  .container-fluid -->
</div>
```

***EDIT***

Use a psuedo element such as..

```
.right:before {
    right: -999em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 example](http://codeply.com/go/YssQ5T7pxq)

---

**Similar question:** [Bootstrap container fill sides with colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574163/bootstrap-container-fill-sides-with-colors/41576164)

Comment: thanks but the background colour for the right panel does not extend to the right edge of the screen

Comment: This will work with a background gradient, try this: 
`<div style="background: linear-gradient(to right,  aquamarine 0%,aquamarine 70%,rebeccapurple 70%,rebeccapurple 100%); padding: 0">`;

Comment: Or see the duplicate question, they are using before and after instead of a background gradient

Comment: @ZimSystem, great answer, thanks