# Bootstrap container fill sides with colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following template using bootstrap :

[image: ![1600px](http://imgur.com/a/PjIH6)]

I'm using a 1200px container for the blue/gray container and the image is 1600px.

I would like to fill the left side of the blue container (400px) with blue and the right side of the gray container (800px) with gray, but the fillers can't go over 1600px. Basically it has to match with the picture above the 2 containers.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

the content has to stay within 1200px, but the background colors must be filled to 1600px.

If I resize the template to 1200ish pixels, it should look like the following picture.

[image]
Do you guys have an idea how I could achieve that? Every solution I tried resolve around ditching the bootstrap container and the content get out of line when i resize, which is something I would like to avoid.

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is a bootply example if needed: http://www.bootply.com/APwOkhCfQD

Comment: I didnt understand what you actually want to do, so let me ask:
What you want is that the blue-gray section have the same width size of the logo?

Comment: Here is a non-resizable example of what I am trying to achieve: http://www.bootply.com/cTUFFpMZxf

Comment: Maybe this could help:
the `.container` class must have a width 100% and a max-width of 1600px. This would prevent the container to get larger than the header but it also would be resizable. Check it out and tell me if that works

Comment: Unfortunately, this would not work because the 2 containers (blue and gray) would be stretched to 1600px. (example : http://www.bootply.com/k4sOVUuBfF). I need to have the content inside the blue and gray container within1200px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem is that the image is hardcoded to `1600px` width. You have two options:

Make your header completely fluid in width and remove double `container` wrap you currently have going on:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container"><!-- delete this -->
```

Or change the `container` class width to `1600`:

```
.container {
    width: 1600px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/q35ERYfN7A

**Update:**

You can also achive the full background color effect via:

```
.blue-background, .light-gray-background{height: 100vh;}
body{background: linear-gradient(90deg, #004a87 50%, #f2f1eb 50%);}
```

Comment: I edited my question because I think it was rather confusing. I hope it is clear enough now, thank you!

Comment: It works except on IE (unsurprisingly), but this is another issue, thank you!

Comment: ie has their own gradient prefixes, this generator is very handy: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Use pseudo classes on .service-container and .commitment-container.  Position them absolutely and size them at 200px wide and 100% height.  Add the background color and voila!

Example:

```
.service-container::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507852/get-two-columns-with-different-background-colours-that-extend-to-screen-edge/41508190#41508190) before.

Put the blue background color on the outer wrapper of `container`, and **add a pseudo element** to the right side with the light gray background.

```
.light-gray-background:before {
    right: -999em;
    background: #f2f1eb;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/Cdnjz5CH5M