# Bootstrap: Set 2 columns to be full width but the text inside them to be aligned with document container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my 2 columns to be different size and background-color, but I want them together to always take up 100% width while the text content stays inside the normal container. Any ideas?

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/de5k2j4n/1/

```
<div class="container">
 <p>
  Text inside container
 </p>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <p>
    Text inside container, but my background wants to take all width on left
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <p>
    Text inside container, but my background wants to take all width on right
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I sketched a picture to visualize my idea:

[image: There are three boxes with text. The first black box is centered and the text goes across it's entire width. Below the text a red and blue box are side by side. They overlap the black box. The text in the red and blue boxes only take up the space where they overlap the black box.]

Comment: Are the borders going to be visible or are those just to demonstrate your idea? Do they need to be different heights like in your image? Also, if you have an attempt at this the code should be in your question.

Comment: Borders just for demonstration. Different height would be nice, but I think that is not the tricky part. I'll add the code to JSfiddle now!

Comment: The code will need to go in the question itself but you can still link to your fiddle as long as the code is here too. You can also create a [runnable snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) from within your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Two Columns with different background colours that extend to screen edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507852/get-two-columns-with-different-background-colours-that-extend-to-screen-edge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered similar questions here:

[Get Two Columns with different background colours that extend to screen edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507852/get-two-columns-with-different-background-colours-that-extend-to-screen-edge/41508190#41508190)

[Bootstrap container fill sides with colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574163/bootstrap-container-fill-sides-with-colors/41576164)

I think the best way is using a full width "wrapper" and pseudo elements to extend the left/right to the sides, while keeping content in the `container`.

```
.left:before {
    left: -999em;
    background: lightgreen;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.right:before {
    right: -999em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/tZsOBff9WH

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I had forgotten about the before/after pseudo elements.