# How can I extend content outside of Bootstrap's columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using Bootstrap 3 on our site and I'm attempting to extend content outside of the container, but am coming up unsuccessful. Here is an image on what I'm trying to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG5iJ.jpg

I would like to use 9 columns on the right of the container for content in 3 sections, and use a div to cover the left 3 columns and extend to the edge of the screen. I have used :before and :after attributes for extending background's to the edge of the screen in the past, but the content has been inside the container. I need the content to go outside of the container if possible. The content above and below this section will be using Bootstraps columns so I'd like to follow suit with the responsiveness and structure.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and we will start from there

Comment: Code snippet you tried will definitely help fetch answers.

Comment: This is a solved prbolem, no?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002499/4408994

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend bootstrap row outside the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002070/extend-bootstrap-row-outside-the-container)