# Extend an element beyond the bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on one of mockups with using Bootstrap 4 and there's one uncommon element inside the container, which background is extending beyond container. Not sure how exactly this thing should be done. I was trying to implement it with position: absolute, but I'm not a fan of it because of broking responsivness in that case.

The problematic element is "Watch the video" text with background.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

[image: Mockup]

```css
/* VIDEO */
.video {
    padding: 70px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.video .video-wrapper p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.video .description-wrapper h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.video .description-wrapper .box {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.bg-colored {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0b3b52;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Videos</title>
</head>
<body>
        <section class="video">

 
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 video-wrapper">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mVWlLQt.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            <p>Name video 5:45</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 description-wrapper">
                           <div class="row align-items-center">
                               <div class="col-md-6 box">
                                   <h3>Keep your club organized online, 
                                        we save time and energy for you!
                                        </h3>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-md-6 box bg-colored">
                                    <h3>Watch the video</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p>
                                    Managing a team could also be a hassle free and easy activity. 
                                    CRM42 is a web based platform with a user friendly interface, offering a comfortable and profitable experience while using it. Create your new management strategy and focus on getting the best results. 
                                    Your goal is now our goal!      
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                    CRM42 gives you a complete solution with a 360-degree view of your players, including complete management of their contracts, injuries, medicals, offers, past teams, even family members, bank accounts and all sponsors information.
                                    Accessible for your entire staff, anytime from anywhere.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                            Let’s make something awesome together!
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the same technique as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002070/extend-bootstrap-row-outside-the-container/42002499#42002499

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002070/extend-bootstrap-row-outside-the-container), but I will answer since Bootstrap 4 flexbox is different than the other 3.x answer.

It can be done with **pseudo element** that extends outside the column:

https://codeply.com/go/tXGn5pdD4A

```
.bg-colored:before {
    right: -999em;
    background:  #0b3b52;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```