# Bootstrap 4 - Two column layout - One fixed, one fluid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to code a website which looks like this:
[image: two columns]

- In one row, two columns
- one behaive like the container would be `container-fluid`, the other like `container`

I tried several ways I could imagine but none worked. This is my output code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 bg-primary text-white">
      <h1>Hey there</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-secondary">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any one an idea? It's important the the margin is the same like container since all elements of the website should start in one line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: Will the fluid div contain content all the way to the right or is it just for extending the background?

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598458/extend-an-element-beyond-the-bootstrap-container

Comment: @Paulie_D It's only to extend the background. The fluid box only is holding a background image.

Comment: Then the links provided have your answer.