# Bootstrap 4 layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, bootstrap-4

Is there a way in bootstrap 4 to get a layout look like the picture link.

[image: layout]

Anyone can give me some suggestion? Thanks.

1 - this is a regular container in bootstrap

2 -div that starts with the container, but its width is to the end of the width of the browser, not to the width of the container

3 - opposite situation to 2

4 - div starting in 6 columns, but its width is to the end of browser width

5- opposite situation to 4

Comment: Look at my breakout. http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/MJNvod This does not use Bootstrap, as I loathe it, but the principle stays the same

Comment: Please show what you've tried and narrow it down to a specific question.

Comment: 1 - this is a regular container in bootstrap 
2 - div that starts with the container, but its width is to the end of the width of the browser, not to the width of the container
3 - opposite situation to 2

4 - div starting in 6 columns, but its width is to the end of browser width
5- opposite situation to 4

Comment: Ok, can you add that to the question instead of the comments? Are the numbered blocks images, background images, etc...? Need more details

Comment: No, they are not pictures, divs with content (Can be anything), but I do not know their height, so absolute positioning is not a solution, or I do not know how to position them to height depends on the content  in the middle div (2,3)

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar questions on Bootstrap 3: [Extend bootstrap row outside the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002070/extend-bootstrap-row-outside-the-container/42002499). There is **no way to do this with Bootstrap "out-of-the-box"**.

The best way I've found is using a CSS pseudo element as it adjusts along with Bootstrap `col-*` and therefore works responsively.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/emc6CJrnca

```
.right {
    z-index: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.right:before {
    background-image:url(..);
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 999em;
    /* allow for bootstrap column padding */
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/emc6CJrnca)

Also see:
[Get Two Columns with different background colours that extend to screen edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507852/get-two-columns-with-different-background-colours-that-extend-to-screen-edge/41508190)

Comment: Thanks, but in my situation this is not a solution.

I can not use pseudo element, I can not use background solution either.

Sections 2,3,4,5, there are divs in which there may be anything, more divs, etc.